# Dygraph : Display Image while loading graph data

Tags: dygraphs

I am new at dygraph and would like to display an image while the graph is getting loaded. Can anyone suggest how to display an image or message when the graph is getting displayed

Answer (score 1):

here i created an example http://jsfiddle.net/cephei/uo7uuxy7/7/

I used spinnerJS library. jsfiddle doesn't let me create an ajax link for Dygraph directly but i think that idea is understandable.

Dygrpah replace the content inside div with id div_g, hence

```
g.ready(function () {
    // stop spinner
    spinner.stop();
});
```

is unnecessary.